# problem related boundary value condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have found two sums in my textbook, I tried but may  be I did somthing wrong 
$ 1) \frac{d^2y}{dx} -4λ\frac{dy}{dx}+4λ^2y =0  $ where $(λ>0)$

Find the eigen value and the eigen fuction of this equation where $y(0)+y_1(0) =0$ and $y(1)-y_1(1)=0$

$ 2) \frac{d^2y}{dx} + λy=0 $ where $(λ>0)$  satisfying the boudary condition $y(0)=y(1)$ and $y_1(0)=y_1(1)$

Solution: $1)$ The Auxiliary solution $m=2λ,2λ$ i.e. $y(x)=(c_1+c_2x)e^{2λx} $
then $y(0)+y_1(0)=0$ Imply $c_2=-c_1(1+2λ)$ but cant go farther because for the $2$nd case it implies $λ= \frac{1}{2}i$ I dont understand what to do.

Solution: $2)$ Using $1$st case I found a relation between the constant $c_1 $and $c_2$ but putting this to case two gives a solution which is diffenrent from my book...

Thanks for your help.....

Answer (score 1):

For case I, the application of the boundary conditions yields to a homogeneous linear system of equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$, which leads to the trivial solution $c_1 = c_2 = 0$ and the only solution to this case is $y = 0$.

For case II, the homogenous solution of the equation is

$$y(x) = c_1 \sin \mu x + c_2 \cos \mu x ,\quad \mu = \sqrt{\lambda}$$

Apply boundary conditions to find

\begin{align*}
& \mu c_1 + c_2 = 0 \\
&  (\mu c_1 + c_2) \cos{\mu} = (\mu c_2 - c_1) \sin{\mu}
\end{align*}

It is clear from the first that $c_2 = - \mu c_1$ and from this result and the second, you find $c_1 (\mu^2 + 1) \sin{\mu} = 0$. This holds if $c_1 =0$ or $\mu = \pm i$ or $\sin{\mu} = 0$. The two first give you the trivial solution and a contradiction, since $\mu > 0$. The only valid alternative is $\sin \mu = 0$, which only occurs for some values of $\mu$. For instance $\mu = \pi$ or $\mu = 7 \pi$.

Can you take it from here and construct the family of all possible solutions?